# Copying some parts of html code and making other link in PHP

Tags: php, html, preg-match, preg-match-all

i wanted to make a function in php , i can explain what i want with an example:

**HTML CODE:**

```
<?php
$html= '
<td id="rsO"><a href="./go.php?q=link"><img height="89" src="http://example.org/1.jpg" width="134"></a><br><cite title="default title">website</cite><br>a picture from america<br>567 × 378 - 47k&nbsp;-&nbsp;jpg</td>
<td id="rsO"><a href="./go.php?q=link"><img height="89" src="http://example.org/1.jpg" width="134"></a><br><cite title="default title">website</cite><br>a picture from germany<br>567 × 378 - 47k&nbsp;-&nbsp;jpg</td>
';
?>
```

**RESULT:**

```
<td id="rsO"><a href="./go.php?q=link&keyword=a picture from america"><img height="89" src="http://example.org/1.jpg" width="134"></a><br><cite title="default title">website</cite><br>a picture from america<br>567 × 378 - 47k&nbsp;-&nbsp;jpg</td>
<td id="rsO"><a href="./go.php?q=link&keyword=a picture from germany"><img height="89" src="http://example.org/1.jpg" width="134"></a><br><cite title="default title">website</cite><br>a picture from germany<br>567 × 378 - 47k&nbsp;-&nbsp;jpg</td>
```

as you see **a picture from america** and **a picture from germany** are copied into the links:

```
...<br>a picture from america<br>...
<a href="./go.php?q=link&keyword=a picture from america">


...<br>a picture from germany<br>...
<a href="./go.php?q=link&keyword=a picture from germany">
```

there are thousand html codes like this i wanna copy all of them into the link without breaking.
thanks.

Comment: "picture from america" will always be in `<br>` ?

Comment: yes. and all in td, like this. `<td><a href="link"></a><br>a pic<br></td>`

Comment: are you sure there will be only one set of <br></br> in a <tb> bcoz i cac see a <br> before <cite> tag..

Comment: i edited my question read it one more time . in `<td></td>` **a picture from america** and **a picture from germany** will be copied into the links.

Comment: it can be between this code `</cite><br>...a pic...<br>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know how effective this but i hope someone can make it better

```
 <?php

$html = '
<td id="rsO"><a href="./go.php?q=link"><img height="89" src="http://example.org/1.jpg" width="134"></a><br><cite title="default title">website</cite><br>a picture from america<br>567 × 378 - 47k&nbsp;-&nbsp;jpg</td>
<td id="rsO"><a href="./go.php?q=link"><img height="89" src="http://example.org/1.jpg" width="134"></a><br><cite title="default title">website</cite><br>a picture from germany<br>567 × 378 - 47k&nbsp;-&nbsp;jpg</td>
';

$strs = array();
$strsCounter = 0;

function collect_keyword($matches) {
    global $strs;
    $strs[] = $matches[0];
    return $matches[0];
}

$patterns = array('/([A-Za-z\s-_]+(?!<\/cite><br>)(?=<br>\d*))/');
preg_replace_callback($patterns, collect_keyword, $html);

function generate_link($matches) {
    global $strs, $strsCounter;
    $return = $matches[0] . '&keyword=' . $strs[$strsCounter];
    $strsCounter++;
    return $return;
}

$patterns = array('/(\.\/go\.php\?q=link)/');
$line = preg_replace_callback($patterns, generate_link, $html);
echo '<table><tr>' . $line . '</tr></table>';
?>
```

Comment: i think youre the best php programmer in the world man, no one could make these php codes. thank you very much.